# QT Creator build qml application

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I build a simple qml app that I want to send to a customer (preferably as a .exe)
When i run build project the executable in the release directory is not doing anything.
With most languages ide's that was all I have to do, click a specific build button that would generate a executable and send it.
Do I need to take extra steps in qt to generate a release for customers?

Comment: I can guess in this case, but normally it's good practice to include some error-code in your question (I think you got 0xc0000135?). You are missing the Qt dll's, which have to be bundled to the application using `windeployqt.exe`

Comment: @Amfasis the .exe does nothing not even showing an error,also tried running as admin.

Comment: Currently on linux so can't try to reproduce, but maybe running from console and checking the exit code `echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%`?

Answer (score 0):

Please read Qt documentation on how to deploy Qt programs on Windows: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Most often you only need to call `windeployqt` to copy all the Qt related DLLs next to your exe file:

```
windeployqt --qmldir path_to/my/src/qml myprogram.exe
```

Then you can zip the folder and send it.

*Note:* If you are using MSVC, you will have a vc_redist.exe file. This is a setup to install the latest Visual C++ runtime, you need to make sure this setup is run before running your program. Usually this is done as part of the installation process of your program, when you distribute it as a "setup.exe".

If you want to send a single exe to a customer, you have 2 choices:

1. Make a setup. Meaning that the user will have to install the program.
2. Link Qt (and all libraries) statically. This means that you have to build your own static Qt library from source. It is not impossible but it is not simple. Also if you are using Qt under an open source license, that your program will be impacted more severely by the LGPLv3.
3. You can compress the folder into a self-extractible zip file. When the customer launch the program, it will extract all files (your main exe file + Qt dlls) into a tmp folder and then start your exe. This adds a significant start up time to your program because you have to unzip all files each time.

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but i do not want to send a folder to a customer, just an executable.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart You cannot do that, or it is complicated. That's why we have setup on Windows. I have added possible solutions to my answer.